# How to make this code print to a .out or .txt file

Tags: c++

I have been trying this for a while and I haven't been able to make this code print to a .txt or .out file. I have added the libraries, correct parameter requirements (I think), and there are no errors in my code (I think). The assignment is past due so I just want to figure this out for myself.

Heres the code (I got it off of cplusplus.com and modified it):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;


    

    struct studentType
        {
            string StudentFName;
            string StudentLName;
            int TestScore;
            char grade;
        };
    
        void readIn(ifstream& inFile, studentType sList[], int listSize);
        void assignGrade(ofstream& outFile, studentType sList[], int listSize);
        int topScore(ofstream& outFile, const studentType sList[], int listSize);
        void printInfo(ofstream& outFile, const studentType sList[], int listSize);
    
        int main()
        {
            ifstream infile;
            ofstream out;
            out << fixed << showpoint;
            out << setprecision(2);
            infile.open("text.txt");
            out.open("Chp9Pr2.txt");
            if (infile.fail())
            {
                cout << "File could not open please check the file" << endl;
                system("pause");
                system("exit");
            }
    
            studentType sList[20];
            readIn(infile, sList, 6);
            assignGrade(out, sList, 6);
            topScore(out, sList, 6);
            printInfo(out, sList, 6);
            infile.close();
            system("pause");
            return 0;
        }
    
        void readIn(ifstream& inFile, studentType sList[], int listSize)
        {
    
            int n = 0;
            while (n < listSize)
            {
                string lineOfFile = "";
                getline(inFile, lineOfFile);
                istringstream iss(lineOfFile);
                if (lineOfFile != "")
                {
                    int numWord = 1;
                    do
                    {
                        std::string sub;
                        iss >> sub;
                        if (numWord == 1)
                            sList[n].StudentFName = sub;
                        else if (numWord == 2)
                            sList[n].StudentLName = sub;
                        numWord++;
                    } while (!iss.eof());
                    if (numWord == 2)
                    {
                        sList[n].StudentLName = "";
                        sList[n].StudentFName = "";`enter code here`
                        inFile >> sList[n].TestScore;
                        n++;
    
                    }
    
                }
    
            }
        }
    
        void assignGrade(ofstream& outFile, studentType sList[], int listSize)
        {
            int i;
    
            for (i = 0; i < listSize; i++)
                if (sList[i].TestScore < 60)
                    sList[i].grade = 'F';
            else if (sList[i].TestScore < 70)
                sList[i].grade = 'D';
            else if (sList[i].TestScore < 80)
                    sList[i].grade = 'C';
            else if (sList[i].TestScore < 90)
                    sList[i].grade = 'B';
                else    
                    sList[i].grade = 'A';
        }
    
        int topScore(ofstream& outFile, const studentType sList[], int listSize)
        {
            int high = 0, i;
            for (i = 0; i < listSize; i++)
                if (high < sList[i].TestScore)
                    high = sList[i].TestScore;
            return high;
        }
    
        void printInfo(ofstream& outFile, const studentType sList[], int listSize)
        {
            cout << left << setw(30) << "Student Name" << right << setw(10) << "TestScore" << right << setw(7) << "Grade" << endl;
            string name;
            int high, i;
            for (i = 0; i < listSize; i++)
            {
                name = sList[i].StudentLName + " " + sList[i].StudentFName;
                cout << left << setw(30) << name << right << setw(10) << sList[i].TestScore << right << setw(7) << sList[i].grade << endl;
            }
    
        
            cout << endl;
            high = topScore(outFile, sList, listSize);
            cout << "Highest Test Score: " << high << endl;
            cout << "Students having the highest test score: " << endl;
            for (int i = 0; i < listSize; i++)
                if (sList[i].TestScore == high)
                    cout << sList[i].StudentLName <<" " << sList[i].StudentFName << endl;
        }
```

Comment: if you could shrink it down to where the issues is comming from it would be a lot simpler

Comment: You are trying to read AND write. What happens if you only try to write? You are not checking the output file open against errors. Please provide a [mre] which demonstrates only the core problem you want to discuss. Ideally without needing input.

Comment: There are no errors that come up when you copy and paste the code. The problem isn't that it won't run the problem is it won't run the intended way. I can't make it print the output to a .txt/.out. That's why the whole code is there.